# awk command to find in files looking different

Tags: awk

Why do not this work? It finds all the other files but not this one. The only difference is that it has numbers in its name.

```
awk -F= '$1=="Icon" {print $2}' "/usr/share/applications/hildon/dropn900.desktop"
```

The file it uses..

```
 [Desktop Entry]
 Version=1.0.0
 Encoding=UTF-8
 Name=DropN900
 Comment=Python based DropBox client
 Exec=/opt/dropn900/dropn900.py
 Icon=dropn900
 X-Icon-path=/usr/share/icons
 X-Window-Icon=dropn900
 Type=Application
 X-Osso-Type=application/x-executable
```

It should give me the output of "dropn900" but doesn't.

---

If i do as suggested below..

```
awk -F= '$1==" Icon" {print $2}' "/usr/share/applications/hildon/fapman.desktop"
```

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Faster Application Manager
Exec=fapman.launch
Icon=fapman
X-Osso-Type=application/x-executable
X-Osso-Service=org.maemo.faster_application_manager
Categories=System;
```

This will not show..

The one suggested by Dennis gave the output.

```
dropn900
/usr/share/icons
dropn900
```

But i need just "dropn900" or the script will not work.

Comment: Thanks Dennis! Yes, that is why. The dropn900.desktop have leading spaces.. Could i manage this problem with just one awk or do i need two?

Comment: @AlMedhi: see my answer below. (Use an @ with a user's name or they might never see replies.)

Comment: @dennis-williamson: Thanks! Will do that in the future. Did not know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F= '$1~/^ *Icon/ {print $2}' file
```

Comment: @ghostdog74: Thanks but it did not work on "fapman" cause it doesn't have leading space.

Comment: Sorry.. forgot the '*'.. now it might work. But i am not sure it is always the first "Icon" that is correct. That the '^' indicates.

Comment: Strange.. now "fapman" gives the correct output in terminal. But don't show when i run it in the script. It's only "fapman" that don't show up of 13.

Comment: My fault.. i went back and checked it more. It finds "fapman" as it should. I found out that this particular icon was in another folder. This is the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using equals, not space, as the field separator, `$1` is actually `" Icon"` **with** a leading space.  Try

```
awk -F= '$1==" Icon" {print $2}'
```

on your file, and you'll see that the file having numbers in its name is really irrelevant.

Comment: hmm.. but now doesn't my other work. like "fapman.desktop". It has the same line "Icon=fapman".

Comment: @AlMehdi, if one value has a leading space and the other one doesn't, then you can't use `==` to compare them both to the same string!  Don't focus on the filename, highlighted in this Q's very-wrong title, which is irrelevant.  Use RE-matching or other ways to check instead.

Comment: ghostdog74 solution worked so i am using that. And true.. i will change the topic.

Answer (score 1):

If some of your files have leading whitespace on each line and some don't, this regex match may help:

```
awk -F= '$1 ~ " *Icon" {print $2}'
```

Comment: @dennis-williamson: It did work in terminal but when i do it in the script. It doesn't find all. Before it just missed the "dropn900" but now it misses five incl. the "dropn900".

Comment: Maybe cause it finds to much.. it gets all the lines with "Icon" in it. Edit my post.